# Encrypt JSON for Android

Tags: java, android, json, encryption

My apps are powered by an engine (sdk/jar) that I wrote. It reads JSON, but the engine is the same across all apps. I realize absolute security is not possible, but I want to make it difficult for someone else to just take my engine from the apk and modify the json to make a new app.

I don't have much experience with encryption. Can I encrypt my json and have my engine decrypt it during app launch?

Comment: Is the JSON saved in a file inside your app like a settings file or something? You can decrypt/encrypt text files all you want of course, but it's going to have an effect on how fast your app loads, so you might want to be careful when doing this.

Comment: can you?  yes.  Encrypting strings should not be difficult, google around for a tutorial.

Comment: Yes, it's in a file. Good to know that I can. Thanks!